# svn proxy precommit handling (server to client) service

Tags: svn, teamcity, pre-commit-hook, svn-server

Is it possible to setup something like svn proxy that can manage the precommit tasks? Lets say that we have our svn branch and we don't have any access to svn server settings. However we want to have something (service) which can see our branch and work as a proxy for svn so developer can commit to this service and after some actions his request will get to the branch. The outside interface should be exactly the same as a normal svn server. So users should not be able to understand if they commit directly or there is something in between. In general something like a gate.

If I have such a setup then I can run a teamcity on this gate without client side integration such as a plugin for vs or command line plugin.

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a more distributed version control system, as opposed to Subversion's centralized model.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't switch to something else therefore I need something like this. Theoretically it should be possible just have the server interface and propagate the calls to the client inside instead of doing actual things.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to test your code before your commit, You can try using [Teamcity's pre-tested commit](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Pre-Tested+%28Delayed%29+Commit) setup .

teamcity has plugins for both eclipse and intellij, so you can basically send a patch of code that would be built,deployed and tested and comiitted only if all the targets have been run succesfully

To add, there are plugins for eclipse,IntelliJ and Visual Studio

Comment: Hi thank you I know that however the goal is to not use the plugin directly on the client side instead just commit somewhere where this plugin will be executed - command line plugin. So I want to make the whole process transparent + prevent anybody to commit without tests.